# Trying to create a spell checker, algorithm isn't working as intended.

Tags: python, spell-checking

I"m trying to write my own spell checking algorithm that also prints out suggestions. It's not quite working as intended and I'm not sure why. I can pick up misspelled words but I can't suggest good ones. Here's my code so far:

```
def corrections_helper(word, testWord):
    count = 0
    charCount = 0
    for char in word:
        if char in testWord:
            charCount += 1
    if charCount >= int(len(testWord) / 1.5):
        for n in range(0, len(testWord)):
            if word[n] != testWord[n]:
                count += 1
    return count

def corrections(item, trieLi):
    suggestions = []
    count = 0
    for word in trieLi:
        if len(word) == len(item):
            if corrections_helper(word, item) <= 3:
                suggestions.append(word)
    print(suggestions)
```

Using the word "propensities" incorrectly spelled as "propensiteis", I get random output that isn't what I intended. For example:

```
['walesordered', 'wigglesworth', 'unsuccessful', 'unfavourable', 'unfrequently', 'undertakings', 'unacquainted', 'unacceptable', 'unaccustomed', 'unproductive', "king'sfisher", 'buffcoloured', 'buryingplace', 'bronzewinged'...
```

And a whole lot of other words that shouldn't be showing up. Where am I going wrong? I don't even know if the correct word is showing up in the large list of return values. Hundreds come back, but none of them are even close.

Comment: you may want to consider levenshtein distance instead.

Comment: your `correction_helper` function is returning 0 for word that have few letters in common

Comment: add an else clause to `if charCount >= int(len(testWord) / 1.5)` that returns a number greater than 3. Or just initialize `count` to a large number

Comment: Thank you, @samgak. That's all I was missing.